# TypeError: PatternFill.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extLst'

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and was watching a tutorial for learning pandas, where the tutorial was about reading a xlsx file and so I tried the same but was getting error.
note: The file taken is a non-empty xlsx file

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\NAME.xlsx", "Sheet1")
print(df)
```

And I was expecting a tabular representation but instead I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\concept practicing in python\pandas practicing.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\NAME.xlsx", "Sheet1")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 478, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1513, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 549, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 540, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 560, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 299, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 94, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\fills.py", line 64, in from_tree
    return PatternFill._from_tree(child)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\fills.py", line 102, in _from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: PatternFill.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extLst'
```

Comment: This just happened to me as well. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you, by any chance, edit these Excel files with SoftMaker's PlanMaker?
[Here you can find a PlanMaker's user question... in 2020](https://forum.softmaker.com/viewtopic.php?t=23185)

I guess that the problem isn't on openpyxl side...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).